# In a JSP, how can I dynamically set the contentType?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, content-type

I have a very simple JSP that looks like this:

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json" %>${actionBean.response}
```

`actionBean.response` returns a `String`.  Sometimes that string is json which has a contentType of "application/json" but sometimes that string is jsonp which has a contentType of "application/javascript".  But I can't figure out how to dynamically set the value of the contentType.

1. I've tried using `<c:choose>` around the contentType but it gives me an error saying that I can't set the contentType twice.
2. I've tried using EL for the value of attribute, but it doesn't get expanded.

Is there a way to dynamically set this value?

Answer (score 4):

You could try using scriptlets (not ideal, but I'm not sure there's another way), like this:

```
<%
    if (actionBean.isJson()) {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
    } else if (actionBean.isJsonp()) {
        response.setContentType("application/javascript");
    }
%>
```

Edit: And as Joop mentions in the comments, make sure you aren't setting a contentType using a @page directive.

Comment: And leaving out the `contentType` attribute from the `@page` directive.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that jsp's are meant to do that.  You would capture a JSON response in a javascript function without the need to declare a content type.

I also never have seen any jsp page turning into a javascript file.

You could use `<s:property name="something" escapeHtml="false" escapeJavascript="false"/>` for both.

Comment: "I do not think that jsp's are meant to do **that**" what exactly is "that" in this sentence?

Comment: have a content-type other than anything in the html range (I might be mistaking about this but in 6 years of developing jsp's with struts I have never seen it)

Comment: OK so what would you do instead?

Comment: Well, JSON is used in javascript so we use ajax calls and capture the result and parse it.  Concerning javascript, it should not be dynamic so you should be able to use a <script src='url'/> declaration.  Dynamic values should be initialized in you page.

Comment: I think you're making an incorrect assumption about what I'm trying to do here.  This JSP is returning the response of an API call.

Comment: But why would an api call need a jsp with content type json?  Surely the json is either the responsibility of javascript or java but not the rendering engine

Comment: I suppose I don't *need* one.  But technically returning the content of the api response is a form of rendering.